# How do I distribute a ruby interpreter with my application

Tags: python, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distributing Ruby/Python desktop apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940149/distributing-ruby-python-desktop-apps)

For python, we have things like py2exe, py2app, freeze.

I only want a runnable application; it can even not be an exe or an app.
I just want to distribute the ruby/python interpreter with all the libraries and my application to the user. It's more like an embedded version of application.

Is there any tools like this for ruby (and for python, maybe)?
It's better if it is cross-platform, including OSX, windows and linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jruby, you can compile it to an executable JAR. See this answer: [Create deployable jruby JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758996/125816).

Comment: And then compile it to .exe via GCJ :)

Answer (score 1):

[Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) lets you package Ruby apps for three platforms.

The [OneClick Ruby Application Builder](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ocra/) can build standalone .exe files for Ruby scripts.

Disclaimer: I have not used either of these tools, so I cannot vouch for their usability or stability.